# mysql need to run optimize every day after batch jobs

Tags: mysql

I have a table with about 4M rows.  Every night, about 15 batch jobs run on the data, with a few hundred thousand inserts and updates.  The problem is, when I run a simple count query such as

```
select count(*) from items;
```

I have to wait for about 15 minutes for it to return.  After researching on SO, I see that

```
optimize table items;
```

does seem to fix the problem, after running it, the above query returns instantly.  The problem is, it takes 17 hours to run.  Any suggestions on what to look for to figure out why this is happening and how to fix it?

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

UPDATE:

Here's what happens when I optimize:

```
mysql> optimize table items;
+------------------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table                  | Op       | Msg_type | Msg_text                                                                |
+------------------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| g_production.items | optimize | note     | Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead |
| g_production.items | optimize | status   | OK                                                                |
+------------------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (9 hours 20 min 48.36 sec)
```

Also, strangely, the select is not using the primary index, ID:

```
explain select count(id) from items;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------------------------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key                      | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------------------------- +---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | items | index | NULL          | index_items_on_real_sale | 2       | NULL | 45152757 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------------------------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.10 sec)
```

And finally, here are all the indexes on the table:

```
+-------+------------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name                                    | Seq_in_index | Column_name    | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| items |          0 | PRIMARY                                     |            1 | id             | A         |    47144790 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| items |          1 | index_items_on_affiliate_id                 |            1 | affiliate_id   | A         |    47144790 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| items |          1 | index_items_on_brand_id                     |            1 | brand_id       | A         |     1024886 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| items |          1 | index_items_on_real_sale                    |            1 | real_sale      | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| items |          1 | index_items_on_retailer_id_and_affiliate_id |            1 | retailer_id    | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| items |          1 | index_items_on_retailer_id_and_affiliate_id |            2 | affiliate_id   | A         |    47144790 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| items |          1 | index_items_on_retailer_id                  |            1 | retailer_id    | A         |       40021 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| items |          1 | index_items_on_shopzilla_id                 |            1 | shopzilla_id   | A         |      457716 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| items |          1 | index_items_on_updated_at                   |            1 | updated_at     | A         |     6734970 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
```

Note the cardinality on the index that the EXPLAIN is revealing, I have 4M rows, but explain says it's using index_items_on_real_sale, which the show indexes command reveals has a cardinality of 18.  Could this be the problem?

Comment: Try `SELECT COUNT(primary_key_field) FROM items`  Outside of that, you need to explain more about your table.  What is table description, what does sample data look like?  What sort of operations are happening on an ongoing basis (i.e. is your count really taking 15 minutes or are you waiting for locks to be released)? What sort of memory allocation do you have for indexes? What is size of that memory allocation relative to size of indexes on table?

Comment: Have you tried running `analyze table` rather than `optimize table`. Optimize table compresses the table and then analyses it. Analyze doesn't do the compression. WARNING Analyze holds a table lock while it is in process, but then so does Optimize.

Comment: Hi, please see update.

Comment: @mikebrant how can i tell what size memory allocation is set?

Answer (score 0):

It could be quite a few things, but I'm wondering if it's indexed properly. Also, try to run the query with explain, like so:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT a,b,c WHERE....
```

Look at the output and see how many rows it's reading to process the query and they type of indexes etc...

Definitely need more information in order to help out, I'm just guessing based on the limited information you provided.